# Example of 'Programming Collective Intelligence' doesn't work

Tags: python, search, search-engine, ranking

I downloaded source code from [here](http://kiwitobes.com/PCI_Code.zip). I tried to run the example from chapter 4 of the book 'Programming Collective Intelligence' by Toby Segaran. My python version is 2.7.2. I type in interpreter this code:

```
import searchengine
pages=['http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language']
crawler = searchengine.crawler('searchindex.db')
crawler.crawl(pages)
```

And get message:

```
Could not open http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language
```

Or sometimes get message:

```
Indexing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language
Could not parse page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language
```

In summary crawler doesn't index the page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Turn `def separateWords(self,text)` the uppercase W into lowercase, and in `gettextonly(self,soup)`, turn `v==Null` into `None`. Also you have to execute the later steps like

```
>> crawler=searchengine.crawler('searchindex.db') 
>> crawler.createindextables()
>> crawler=searchengine.crawler('searchindex.db')
```

first, then try to run `page=['***']` and other steps.